# Training a decision tree with K-Fold - Is this the correct approach?

Tags: python, pandas, validation, scikit-learn

I've used two approaches with the same SKlearn decision tree, one approach using a validation set and the other using K-Fold. I'm however not sure if I'm actually achieving anything by using KFold. Technically the Cross Validation does show a 5% rise in accuracy, but I'm not sure if that's just the pecularity of this particular data skewing the result.

For my implementation of KFold I first split the training set into segments using:

```
 f = KFold(n_splits=8)
 f.get_n_splits(data)
```

And then got data-frames from it by using

```
y_train, y_test = y.iloc[train_index], y.iloc[test_index]
```

In a loop, as witnessed in many online tutorials on how to do it. However, here comes the tricky part. The tutorial I saw had a .train() function which I do not think this decision tree classifier does. Instead, I just do this:

```
    tree = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
    tree.fit(X_train, y_train)
    predictions = tree.predict(X_test)
```

The accuracy scores achieved are:

```
Accuracy score: 0.79496591505
Accuracy score: 0.806502359727
Accuracy score: 0.800734137389
... and so on
```

But I am not sure if I'm actually making my classifier any better by doing this, as the scores go up and down. Isn't this just comparing 9 independent results together? Is the purpose of K-fold not to train the classifier to be better?

I've read similar questions and found that K-fold is meant to provide a way to compare between "independent instances" but I wanted to make sure that was the case, not that my code was flawed in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the purpose of K-fold not to train the classifier to be better?

The purpose of the K-fold is to prevent the classifier from over fitting the training data. So on each fold you keep a separate test set which the classifier has not seen and verify the accuracy on it. You average your prediction to see how best your classifier is performing.

> Isn't this just comparing 9 independent results together?

Yes, you compare the different scores to see how best your classifier is performing

Comment: Alright. Do you know why the accuracy would be 5% higher using k-fold as opposed to just a validation set? Is it just an accident?

Comment: So in the validation approach. you divide the data into test and train. But how you divide fairly is one way that accounts for your low accuracy. In order to cater against it we do k fold cross validation. Could you accept the answer if meets your needs?

Comment: @MateuszJ In the KFold, you have specified splits=8, so that means each time about 88% of data will be used for training and 12% (100/8) of data for testing. In the custom validation set you are talking about in the above comment, are you using the same amount of data ? I think not. Thats why the accuracy is changing.

Comment: My dataset is pretty big so I thought the sizes wouldn't impact it that much, but thanks, I guess that explains it.

Comment: @MateuszJ This is an assumption that you are making. Cross validation is more empirical.

Answer (score 1):

In general using cross validation prevents overfitting. For that you split the data in multiple parts and evaluate the loss, accuracy or other metrics (e.g. `f-1 score`). A good introduction can be found on the official site [[1](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#cross-validation-evaluating-estimator-performance)].

---

In addition I would recommend using `StratifiedKFold` [[2](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html#sklearn-model-selection-stratifiedkfold)] instead of `KFold`.

```
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=8)
skf.get_n_splits(X, y)
```

> This cross-validation object is a variation of KFold that returns stratified folds. The folds are made by preserving the percentage of samples for each class.

So you have balanced labels.